# Incorrect wording for "Top Network Users" on Stack Exchange front page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, wording

So, I noticed last week that [the wording for the Stack Exchange Front Page was confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236473/confusing-wording-for-top-network-users-on-stack-exchange-front-page).

Well, it turns out that the wording is actually completely incorrect.

[Travis J](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178816/travis-j) noticed that all of the users on the front page are the OPs of the questions listed there.

This area is the issue:

[image: Location of area]

It reads

> #### Top Network Users
>
> These users asked or provided top answers for the posts on this page

I found that confusing, so I proposed this wording (provided by [random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random)):

> #### Top Network Users
>
> These users provided the top questions and answers on this page

But, again, the users listed there are the ones who *asked* the questions; none answered them:

[image: Question askers]
(click for larger image)

Since all of the "Top Network Users" are the askers, it should be something like this:

> #### Top Network Users
>
> These users asked the questions listed on this page

Either that, or answerers of those questions should be included along with the askers.

Comment: Was about to ask a question about what is "Top Network Users", as I found the description is quite confusing. What is the purpose of displaying these, with their name already in the questions list? Shouldn't  it be more meaningful if *"Top Network Users"* lists the real top user (with the highest rep. for example) of each site?

Comment: I'm noticing that this is still the case. I guess that it's low priority but it does seem to need addressing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went with a slightly more radical approach:

> [image]

Coming to a stackexchange.com near you in the next prod build.