# "Top Network Users" should contain themselves!

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

Leaving aside that the "Top Network Users" are [*not* the top network users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236893/), they really have a problem keeping their ego in check:

> [image: overboarding username length]

There is a relatively simple fix for this:

```
.userLinks {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That user surely [breaks lots of things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242944/long-display-name-with-no-spaces-breaks-design-of-suggested-edits-history)! ;)